# React-native-navigation: goBack() doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I use React Navigation with Redux in React Native.
Navigation is working fine, but on one screen the goBack() function doesn't work. Can you tell we why?

This is the header config:

```
static navigationOptions = {
        header: ({ state, goBack }) => {
            return {
                title: state.params.name,
                right: (<Button
                    title={'Done'}
                    onPress={() => goBack()}
                />)

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the dispatched event:

[image]

**No Screen is poped off. The Screen on the device stays the same.**

Answer (score 16):

Try
`<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}>`

when **null** is used as input parameter it will bring you to the last page(immediate history) and it helps in situations where nested **StackNavigators** to go back on a parent navigator when the child navigator already has only one item in the stack.

They may change in future because according to their documentation there are planning to change it.

For more information check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back) .

Answer (score 7):

I think, if you want to use the goBack() action you have to to something like this in your View (not header)

```
<Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
```

Comment: Tested this one, too. Doesn't work eather...

Looks like an issue with the react-native-navigation libary:
[gitHub Issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1522)

Comment: this only works when u don't want to use function. When u use a function with onPress and use navigation.goback(), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

GoBack is a bit flaky, excplicitly dispatching the action worked for me.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I do not know why but writing goBack(null) works for me :|

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for this.

this is my working code :-

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => {
     return {
         title:'SECOND',
         headerStyle:{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff'},
         headerTitleStyle:{fontSize:12},
         headerLeft:<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.goBack()}>
                      <Image source={{uri:'back_btn'}} style={{height: 20, width: 20,marginLeft:10,}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **working solution** posted in the [github issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1522):

```
setTimeout(this.props.navigation.goBack, 0)
```

Apparently this bug is a recent regression.

Answer (score 0):

According to a solution posted on this [github issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1522). Passing `null` as an argument to the `goBack` function should work just fine as it did for me. The following code should work in case of OP:

```
static navigationOptions = {
        header: ({ state, goBack }) => {
            return {
                title: state.params.name,
                right: (<Button
                    title={'Done'}
                    onPress={() => goBack(null)}
                />)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `StackActions` API is what broke the navigation in my app. By navigating to a screen with only the (simpler and more reliable) `NavigationActions` API, the back button worked.

Answer (score 0):

> react-navigation

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.props.navigation.goback() }}>
 <Text>Back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

> react-native-router-flux

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Actions.pop() }}>
 <Text>Back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```