# react-navigation goBack doesn't works

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have 2 screen here. First LoginScreen and LoginFormScreen. Let say, LoginScreen have a button, LoginButton : Navigate to LoginFormScreen. 
The activity flow should be

> LoginScreen.js -> LoginFormScreen.js

So here my `AppNavigator.js`

```
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import LoginFormScreen from '../screens/LoginFormScreen'

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({ 
    Login: {screen : LoginScreen},
    LoginForm: {screen: LoginFormScreen},
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Login',
}));
```

On my LoginScreen button, here action that handled onPress

```
<Button
   title="Log In"
   titleStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18 }}
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginForm')}
```

And on my LoginFormScreen, I want to once user click back physical button then return to previous screen (LoginScreen). Here are my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
  }

  handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    this.props.navigation.goBack("Login")
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
    return true;
  }
```

Have tried all those code above and nothing works with me. Have check other solution on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982177/react-native-navigation-goback-doesnt-work) and [GitHub](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1522) including [react-navigation homepage](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html) but no the solution works.

Have try `goBack()`, `goBack(null)`, `dispatch(NavigationActions.back())` and no one works.

Please someone help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `createSwitchNavigator` instead of `createStackNavigator` where you can push and pop the screens and in createSwitchNavigator as the doc says there will only be a single screen visible at a time i.e. no stack will be present you can do

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')`

Comment: I already upvoted it and Yohnaes Al can only accept it, if it help him :)

Comment: my bad I thought you were OP